# MySQL time zone

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to database development and am currently working in MySQL.
I have a column that contains all the time zones for USA. I want to be able to get the current time (only time, no date) as of right now for each time zone in each row.

The TimeZone data looks like: +05:00, -03:00 etc etc etc

This is how I have attempted it. I have 2 tables, one country, one city. TimeZone is found within "city" table. I have tried to use the function sys date() but it returns the complete date and the current time on my system, not based on the time zone. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot

```
 select TimeZone, Country, sysdate() as "Current Time"  
 from city, country 
 where Country='USA' and city.CountryId= country.CountryId;
```

Comment: Are you using the timezone definitions that are built into mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Comment: +05:00, -03:00 is a bad way to store timezones. When daylight savings time occurs you won't know which timezones need to be adjusted. The proper thing to do is to use the store timezone names such as "America/New_York", "America/Chicago" etc.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Thanks for the reply. I did not design/create the table. My job is just to query it, do you know what function would help me or how to go about this? Thanks again

Comment: If you are only storing offsets from UTC (+05:00) then half the year you will be an hour off for cities/states that use daylight savings time. There are some states such as Arizona that do not do daylight savings time.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I have all the cities in the USA along with the timezone for each one. I need to display the current time for each city as of this moment. Is that what your referring too? Sorry, please bear with me like I said I am new at this. Thanks

Comment: Take New York for example. When DST is not in effect it is in timezone -5:00, but when it is in timezone -04:00. Since your database is only storing one of these your times will be off by one hour when daylight savings time rolls around.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I think I understand what you are saying. But how would I implement that in a query, like the one I have shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [convert_tz](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-07:00', city.TimeZone) AS Time, city.Name
    FROM city, country 
    WHERE country.Name='USA' and city.CountryId= country.CountryId;
```

Assuming your server is in -07:00 timezone.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did : select TimeZone, Country, City, convert_tz(now(),-07:00,TimeZone) from city, country where Country='USA' and city.CountryId= country.CountryId;  but it is telling me there is an error with my syntax.. did I do the -07:00 correct?

Comment: Add quotes around -07:00 like '-07:00'.